# Copy file names from one folder to another while keeping the original extensions

Tags: windows, file, powershell, renaming

I need help with copying file *names* (not the files themselves) from C drive to D drive. I was able to find the following powershell code online:

```
$names = @()
$getPath = "C:\MyFiles"
$setPath = "D:\MyFiles"
Get-ChildItem $getPath |
    Foreach-object{
    $names += $_
}
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem $setPath |
Foreach-object{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $names[$i]
    $i++
}
```

This code successfully renames/copies all file names from `C:\MyFiles` to `D:\MyFiles`, strictly by corresponding *positions* (indices in the enumeration).

However, it is also updating the *extensions*, so for instance:

`C:\MyFiles\myfile.txt` renames `D:\MyFiles\thisfile.docx` to `D:\MyFiles\myfile.txt`

Is there a way to edit the Powershell code to only rename the *base* of the filename (e.g., `myFile`) while keeping the target files' *extensions* (e.g., `.docx`)?

So that `C:\MyFiles\myfile.txt` renames `D:\MyFiles\thisfile.docx` to `D:\MyFiles\myfile.docx`, using the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to *rename* files in a target directory *positionally*, based on corresponding files in a source directory - while retaining the target directory files' extensions:

```
$getPath = "C:\MyFiles"
$setPath = "D:\MyFiles"
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -File $getPath

$iRef = [ref] 0
Get-ChildItem -File $setPath | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $sourceFiles[$iRef.Value++].BaseName + $_.Extension }
```

- To *preview* the resulting filenames, append `-WhatIf` to to the `Rename-Item` call.
- The `.BaseName` property of the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` objects output by `Get-ChildItem` returns the file-name portion without the extension.
- `$_.Extension` extracts the input file's (i.e., the target file's) existing extension, including the leading `.`
- Note that the script block (`{ ... }`) passed to `Rename-Item` creates a *child* variable scope, so you cannot increment a variable in the caller's scope *directly* (it would create a new copy of such a variable with the original value every time); therefore, a `[ref]` instance is created to *indirectly* hold the number, which the child scope can then modify via the `.Value` property.

---

Here's a **complete example**:

<sup>Note: While this example uses similar file names and uniform extensions, the code works *generically*, with *any* names and extensions.</sup>

```
# Determine the temporary paths.
$getPath = Join-Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ('Get' + $PID)
$setPath = Join-Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())  ('Set' + $PID)

# Create the temp. directories.
$null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force $getPath, $setPath

# Fill the directories with files.

# Source files: "s-file{n}.source-ext"
"--- Source files:"
1..3 | % { New-Item -ItemType File (Join-Path $getPath ('s-file{0}.source-ext' -f $_)) } | 
  Select -Expand Name

# Target files: "t-file{n}.target-ext"
"
---- Target files:"
1..3 | % { New-Item -ItemType File (Join-Path $setPath ('t-file{0}.target-ext' -f $_)) } | 
  Select -Expand Name

# Get all source names.
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -File $getPath

# Perform the renaming, using the source file names, but keeping the
# target files' extensions.
$i = 0; $iVar = Get-Variable -Name i
Get-ChildItem -File $setPath | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $sourceFiles[$iVar.Value++].BaseName + $_.Extension }

"
---- Target files AFTER RENAMING:"

Get-ChildItem -Name $setPath

# Clean up.
Remove-Item -Recurse $getPath, $setPath
```

The above yields:

```
--- Source files:
s-file1.source-ext
s-file2.source-ext
s-file3.source-ext

---- Target files:
t-file1.target-ext
t-file2.target-ext
t-file3.target-ext

---- Target files AFTER RENAMING:
s-file1.target-ext
s-file2.target-ext
s-file3.target-ext
```

Note how the target files now have the source files' base file names (`s-file*`), but the target files' original extensions (`.target-ext`).